# bundle exec on procution faild and application.rb load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

While moving my rails application to production. I need to execute the following command

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

while executing this command, I got the following load error

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- /home/ubuntu/api/config/application
/home/ubuntu/api/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/ubuntu/api/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I created an application using rails 5. How do I shift my rails app to production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `RAILS_ENV` before the command and break the command please

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile 

RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
```